# I have a problem with a mouseclicked funktion in proccessing

Tags: function, class, processing

In my main class i have made an array to spawn a few green circles. I tried to get the background to change when i clicked on one of them with a boolean which is supposed to come true when clicking while over the circle... I am new to programming as a whole and I am not really sure how to solve this problem.. I dont really know where the data of the x and y positions of the green circles are displayed and how the klicked function is supposed to find them because all of them are created at random positions and in an other class. So here is my code so far:

```
class Gesicht {

  //Eigenschaften
  boolean fail = false;
  float whEllipse= 200;
  float yPos = random(-whEllipse, height);
  float  xPos = random(-whEllipse, height);
  float xSpeed = 1;
  float P = 1;

  //Constructor
  Gesicht() {
    // this.yPos = yPos;
    // this.xPos = xPos;
  }

  //Methoden/Funktionen
  void move() {
    //paint();
    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += (P*sin(radians(xPos))+1); //+1 macht dass sich das Gesicht langsam runter bewegt.
    if (xPos>= width+whEllipse/2) {

      // P = P+1; Maybe falls ich größere Amplitude will

      xPos = -whEllipse/2;
    }
    if (yPos >= height+whEllipse/2) {
      yPos = random(-whEllipse, height/2);
      xPos = random(-200, whEllipse/2);
    }
  }

  boolean klicked() {
    if (mouseX > xPos-whEllipse/2 && mouseX < xPos+whEllipse/2
      && mouseY > yPos-whEllipse/2 && mouseY < yPos+whEllipse/2
      && mousePressed) {
     
      return true;
    
      }
    return false;
  }
  
  void klick() {
    if (klicked()) {
      fail = true;
    }
  }
  
  void spawn() {
    move();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    circle(xPos, yPos, whEllipse);
  }
}
```

this is the class where i tried to put my funktions.

```
int farbe = 255;
Gesicht[] grün;
Gesichter[] rot;
Gesichterer[] blau;

void settings() {
  size(700, 700);
}


void setup() {
  rot = new Gesichter[10];
  for ( int i = 0; i< rot.length; i++) {
    rot[i]= new Gesichter();
  }
  grün = new Gesicht[15];
  for ( int i = 0; i< grün.length; i++) {
    grün[i]= new Gesicht();
  }
  blau = new Gesichterer[20];
  for ( int i = 0; i< blau.length; i++) {
    blau[i]= new Gesichterer();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(farbe);
if(variable.klicked()){
  background(150,0,0);
}
  for ( int i = 0; i< grün.length; i++) {
    grün[i].spawn();
  }
    for ( int i = 0; i< rot.length; i++) {
      rot[i].spawn();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< blau.length; i++) {
      blau[i].spawn();
    }
  }
```

And this is my main class.

The funktion never gets true in the moment... I hope someone can help me ://
Would be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. That's a good start if you want to get useful answers. A way to improve on that is to reduce the complexity of your code. Only share what's really important to reproduce the error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure to study documentation and help sites of the software you're using before posting, e.g. [processing's mouse clicked](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying a bit hard without cleaning up your code which on long run leads to more headaches.

I say based on the following:

- you have a `klicked()` but also a `klick()` method which doesn't do much: `klick()` should suffice
- You only define a `Gesicht` class, however you additioanlly attempt to instantiate `Gesichter` and `Gesichterer` which don't exist (at least not in the code you posted)
- `if(variable.klicked()){ background(150,0,0); }` refers to an unusuable variable called `variable` (a placeholder perhaps?). Even if that variable existed, the red background would've only briefly flashed while `klicked()` was true.

You're very close though:

- the `klicked()` method does what you want
- `farbe` already stores the background colour

You could do something like this:

```java
class Gesicht {

  //Eigenschaften
  boolean fail = false;
  float whEllipse= 200;
  float yPos = random(-whEllipse, height);
  float  xPos = random(-whEllipse, height);
  float xSpeed = 1;
  float P = 1;

  //Constructor
  Gesicht() {
    // this.yPos = yPos;
    // this.xPos = xPos;
  }

  //Methoden/Funktionen
  void move() {
    //paint();
    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += (P*sin(radians(xPos))+1); //+1 macht dass sich das Gesicht langsam runter bewegt.
    if (xPos>= width+whEllipse/2) {

      // P = P+1; Maybe falls ich größere Amplitude will

      xPos = -whEllipse/2;
    }
    if (yPos >= height+whEllipse/2) {
      yPos = random(-whEllipse, height/2);
      xPos = random(-200, whEllipse/2);
    }
  }

  boolean klicked() {
    if (mouseX > xPos-whEllipse/2 && mouseX < xPos+whEllipse/2
      && mouseY > yPos-whEllipse/2 && mouseY < yPos+whEllipse/2
      && mousePressed) {

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void klick() {
    if (klicked()) {
      fail = true;
    }
  }

  void spawn() {
    move();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    circle(xPos, yPos, whEllipse);
  }
}

int farbe = 255;
Gesicht[] green;
Gesicht[] rot;
Gesicht[] blau;

void settings() {
  size(700, 700);
}


void setup() {
  //rot = new Gesicht[10];
  //for ( int i = 0; i< rot.length; i++) {
  //  rot[i]= new Gesicht();
  //}
  //green = new Gesicht[15];
  //for ( int i = 0; i< green.length; i++) {
  //  green[i]= new Gesicht();
  //}
  blau = new Gesicht[20];
  for ( int i = 0; i< blau.length; i++) {
    blau[i]= new Gesicht();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(farbe);
  //if (variable.klicked()) {
  //  background(150, 0, 0);
  //}
  //for ( int i = 0; i< green.length; i++) {
  //  if(green[i].klicked()){
  //    farbe = color(red(farbe), random(255), blue(farbe));
  //  }
  //  green[i].spawn();
  //}
  //for ( int i = 0; i< rot.length; i++) {
  //  rot[i].spawn();
  //}
  for (int i = 0; i< blau.length; i++) {
    if(blau[i].klicked()){
      farbe = color(red(farbe), green(farbe), random(255));
    }
    blau[i].spawn();
  }
}
```

(Only one array of circles is uncommented for simplicity/easy testing. Feel free to adjust as needed)

One final touch you could add, if you want the background to only change once when you click (as opposed to continously while the mouse is pressed), is debouncing. The idea is to use a state/variable to keep track if the button was previously pressed or not to only chance the background once until the states change again. (You could implement this using an extra boolean variable in your class or perhaps simpler, use the [mouseClicked()](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) callback to iterate over your array simply to check which instance has been `klicked()` to change the background accordingly).